# Can I use java to create plot file (gif, jpg, etc) on Unix server without referencing display to any running X11 system or frame buffer, VNC, etc?

Tags: java, headless

Is there a way to use java to create plot file (gif, jpg, etc) on Unix server environment without referencing DISPLAY variable to any system running X11 or frame buffer or VNC, etc? I was reading about headless java options since Java 6, but still could not understand if this is possible to do, and if it is, then how to accomplish it.

Comment: What do you not understand about it? What have you tried to do to make headless work, where is this failing, what are the symptoms ?

Comment: I tried to start java with -Djava.awt.headless=true on the server but it was still giving headless exception  when I was instatiating Frame in order to use it to generate GIF file.